# Позиционирование блоков с возможностью адаптации для мобилок

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Имеется два блока, внутри ссылка, как отцентрировать ссылки по вертикали так, что бы при попытках сделать адаптив всё не слетало, мучаюсь целый день... Скрины что хочу приложил, код тоже. [Обычная версия](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWWmp.png) - [Адаптивная версия](https://prnt.sc/y1lzaz) (блок с ссылкой должен быть на весь экран, а когда проматываешь, то следующий тоже на весь)

Вёрстка - https://codepen.io/SadxDarkness/pen/eYdbLQz

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.main {
  display: flex;
}
.about {
  width: 50%;
  background: black;
  height: 100vh;
}
.works {
  width: 50%;
  background: white;
  height: 100vh;
}
.link1 {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 3px solid white;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: "Jura", sans-serif;
}
.link2 {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: "Jura", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="third.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jura:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapperMain">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="about">
                <a href="" class="link1">Обо мне</a>
            </div>
      <div class="works">
                <a href="" class="link2">Портфолио</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оно?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
}

.about,
.works {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: flex-start;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.about {
  background: black;
}

.works {
  background: white;
}

.link1 {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 3px solid white;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: "Jura", sans-serif;
}

.link2 {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: "Jura", sans-serif;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .main {
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
  }
  .about,
  .works {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="third.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jura:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapperMain">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="about">
        <a href="" class="link1">Обо мне</a>
      </div>
      <div class="works">
        <a href="" class="link2">Портфолио</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Оно, но теперь я не понимаю как это в адаптив перевести, ведь после перехода в него, "обо мне " остаётся по центру, а вот портфолио уходит в левый бок...